# Plugin.FirebaseAuth.FirebaseAuthException: An error occurred when accessing the keychain Xamarin.forms app

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios, keychain

I'm using the latest stable package of Plugin.FirebaseAuth (4.1.0). But when I try to call the SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password) when using the iOS simulator. I get an exception?

Method:

```
public async Task<bool> SignIn(string email, string password)
{
    try
    {

        var result = await CrossFirebaseAuth.Current.Instance.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);
        var token = await result.User.GetIdTokenAsync(true);
        Preferences.Set("MyFirebaseRefreshToken", token);
        AccountManager.CurrentUserId = result.User.Uid;
        return true;
    }
    catch (FirebaseAuthException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Reason);
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert($"Alert", (ex.Reason.ToString()), "OK");
        return false;
    }
}`
```

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it only happens to ios, that's maybe because you didn't add the Team ID prefix before your App ID. Like this:

```
Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup("XK********.com.matkonit.SharedItems")
```

You can refer to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60591681/an-error-occurred-when-accessing-the-keychain).

Comment: Unfortunately I did add the teamID prefix. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok So the issue turns out to be with the simulator for iOS.

The fix:
You'll need an apple developer account, and a provisioning profile. You'll also need a custom entitlements.plist

Comment: What does your entitlements.plist look like for this?